# can't remember my pass word for my account

Tags: pokemon-go

I did not use Google Accounts to sign up. 
It was my email and a password. (Pokemon Trainer Club)

My son plays it, actually he got kicked out and he hit a button (probably Google) with a different account and now I can't remember the password because it keeps him signed in all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the button **Forgot your password?**
To reset and set a new password.

Because you used your **E-Mail** and a password

You can request a new password which will be sent to your E-Mail,

If this doesn't work the only persons who can manage accounts is the pokemon go support.

Comment: i tried that and it never does anything when i hit forgot password thats why I'm here thanks though and how could i get a hold of pokemon go support

Comment: somewhere at pokemon.com/support let me try...